# Calculating left UIBarButtonItem width

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I found out the hard way UIBarButtonItem frame width is 0.  After googling, i found a method to traverse the nav controllers subviews to find the left bar button's width.  It works but it just seems like there has to be a cleaner way to do this.

There would be no reason my app would get rejected for using this method right?

```
    UIView *leftBarButtonView = nil;
    for (UIView* v in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        if ([[v class].description isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"])  {
            if (leftBarButtonView==nil) {
                if (v.frame.origin.x > 0.0)
                    leftBarButtonView = v;
            } else if (v.frame.origin.x < leftBarButtonView.frame.origin.x && v.frame.origin.x>0.0) {
                leftBarButtonView = v;  // this view is further right
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't probably get rejected - **probably**, as *nobody* except Apple can say it for sure. However, one thing is sure:

```
[[v class].description isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"]
```

won't work. Use

```
[v isKindOfClass:objc_getClass("UINavigationButton")]
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks.  The first case does work as the code i posted was tested, but the second version seems cleaner.